# Can I use interpolation to access an attribute of a specific block of a resource?

Tags: terraform

An `azurerm_service_fabric_cluster` resource requires one or more `node_type` blocks:

```
resource "azurerm_service_fabric_cluster" "processing" {
  ...
  node_type {
    name = "foo"
    client_endpoint_port = 19000
    ...
  }
  node_type {
    name = "bar"
    client_endpoint_port = 19001
    ...
  }
}
```

I want to access an attribute of a specific `node_type` block, either by `name` or by index. Surprisingly this doesn't give an error when calling `terraform plan`:

```
resource "azurerm_lb_probe" "service_fabric_client_endpoint" {
  port = "${azurerm_service_fabric_cluster.processing.node_type.client_endpoint_port}"
  ...
}
```

Comment: So you need clearly tell us what's the real problem and what you need set?

Comment: You cannot - each terraform resource has an Attributes Reference and those are the only attributes of azurerm_service_fabric_cluster (id, cluster_endpoint ).

Comment: @BMW I've updated the question a bit, but this is a real problem. I know I can also solve it by having a variable and using it in both places, but I wanted to know whether this is possible.

Comment: @victorm `azurerm_resource_group` only has `id` in the Attributes Reference, but I can still use `resource_group_name = ${azurerm_resource_group.default.name}"` in other resources.